# Click outside of a div spec with capybara

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I am currently have a modal that pops up on a button click. I have the implementation working where if a user clicks outside the main modal-dialog, that it'll close the modal.

I am writing specs now with rspec and capybara. My before block

```
  before do
    find("#inquiries-new").click
    should_not have_content('CAMPAIGN INQUIRY')
  end
```

I get this when I run the spec

```
  1) Inquiry popup close popup by clicking outside modal-dialog open again to test duplicated view
  Sauce public job link: 
     Failure/Error: should_not have_content('CAMPAIGN INQUIRY')
       expected not to find text "CAMPAIGN INQUIRY" in "Lorem Ipsum Customers Close CAMPAIGN INQUIRY NAME EMAIL COMPANY CAMPAIGN TITLE BUDGET PHONE DESCRIPTION SEND INQUIRY"
     # ./spec/features/home/inquiry_popup_spec.rb:34:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Is there a way to create a spec for this behavior?

Answer (score 2):

```
page.find(:xpath, "//*[text()='#{text_to_click}']").click
```

Where `text_to_click` is some text outside your model.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to click outside of the modal by executing some javascript with capybara

```
    page.execute_script('$(document.elementFromPoint(50, 350)).click();')
```

The coordinates worked for my specific case, but others should be able to edit them for whatever suits their situation.